# Instance member can't be accessed from a static method Flutter

Tags: flutter

Any idea why I' getting that error ?

```
class appBlocs with ChangeNotifier {
  final geo = geolocation();
  final services = placesCall();

  static Position current;
  static List<places> searchResponse;

  appBlocs() {
    setLocation();
  }

  setLocation() async {
    current = await geo.showCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  searching(String term) async {
    searchResponse = await services.autocomplete(term);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

the error shows at this line onChanged: (value) => appBlocs.searching.
I'm kind of lost to be honest

```
      body: (appBlocs.current == null)
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: ' Search your Bakery ...',
                        suffix: Icon(Icons.search)),
                    onChanged: (value) => appBlocs.searching,
                  ),
                ),
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is your `appBlocs` in `appBlocs.searching` a class instance or the class itself? I'm assuming that it's not a class instance.

Comment: appBlocs it's the class itslef and searching is part of the class, you can have a look to the class on the first code

Comment: If so, you can make `searching(...) async {` to `static searching(...) async {`. Or, get the instance of your provider by `Provider.of<appBlocs>(context, listen: false).searching(value),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more on the use of `static` in Dart/ Flutter [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods).

For example, if you have an AppBlocs class (you should name it in UpperCamelCase according to [the styling guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase))

```dart
class AppBlocs with ChangeNotifier {
  final geo = geolocation();
  final services = placesCall();

  static Position current;
  static List<places> searchResponse;

  appBlocs() {
    ...
  }

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  searching(String term) async {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then to use the inside properties and method, you need to use like this:

```dart
// For static variables and methods
var current = AppBlocs.current
var response = AppBlocs.searchResponse;

// For non-static ones
final bloc = AppBlocs(); // Need to instantiate the object before using them
var geo = bloc.geo
var services = bloc.services
var searching = bloc.searching()
```

In your example, you can see this line is misusing the non-static method `searching()`:

```dart
...
TextField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: ' Search your Bakery ...',
       suffix: Icon(Icons.search)),
       onChanged: (value) => appBlocs.searching, <-----
),
```

You'll need to use it the non-static way, which is:

```dart
...
TextField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: ' Search your Bakery ...',
       suffix: Icon(Icons.search)),
       onChanged: (value) => appBlocs().searching, <-----
),
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it!

```
final geo = geolocation();
final services = placesCall();

//Remove static from this
static Position current;
static List<places> searchResponse;

//To this
Position current;
List<places> searchResponse;
```

Comment: Both current and searchResponse weren't Static, I had the same problem with current and adding static resolved my problem, but I'm getting the same problem now with searching